# Spacing in ul CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and I have a css issue.
Here is the little(big) problem: [Edited pic]

[image: problem of spacing]

I want to remove that space ..... (between the second and the third element)

Here is the source code:

```css
nav {
  z-index: 100;
  background: url(../images/slider-bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  height: 571px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.menu {
  margin: 0px 0px 0 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Cabin Sketch', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px
}

ul.menu li:hover a,
ul.menu li.current a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="logo"><br/>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logoPetit.png" alt=""></a>
  </h1>
  <nav>
    <div id="slide">
      <div class="slider">
        <ul class="items">
          <li><img src="images/slider-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
          <li><img src="images/slider-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
          <li><img src="images/slider-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
      <a href="#" class="next"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="current"><a href="index.php" class="clr-1">Acceuil</a></li>
      <li><a href="projetPedagogique.php" class="clr-2">Projet pédagogique</a></li>
      <li><a href="vie.php" class="clr-3">Vie dans l'école</a></li>
      <li><a href="classe.php" class="clr-4">Classe</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.php" class="clr-5">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.php" class="clr-7">Gallerie</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I put the html code in a snippet (I don't really know what it is) because it appears as executed.

Pleease help me !

Comment: Can you show the exact output please? :) With all the CSS. This will attract down votes otherwise.

Comment: Also illustrate the space problem. Is it the space between 2nd and 3rd menu?

Comment: @ManojKumar this code is a small part of a big thing so I can't really copy everything ..... if you need something else there please tell me.

Comment: Ok. If you can at least show the site or make a [`Plnkr`](https://plnkr.co/) project. That would do.

Comment: This is the site: lEnvol.ma

Comment: You just need to disable the columns. http://lenvol.ma/css/style.css Line no. 95 and 96 Here is the result: https://prnt.sc/k1bm1n

Comment: Yes !! I thought because I used a class there the other style wont be used ^^' ... thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Good. Now answer your own question and mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

Please add another property `text-align` to left in this...

```css
ul.menu li a {
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Cabin Sketch', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I already tried it before .... no change .... thank you for your answer.

Comment: then try this, ul. menu li​ {display:inline;} and ul. menu li a {display:inline-block;}

Comment: I did that before didn't work Manoj Kumar's answer is it .... I just forgot about a style ^^' .... thanks for you help !